# how i can use scriplet tags inside other (ejs)

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs

This is giving me error:

```
<% for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++){ %>
      <% if(arr[i].site==**<%=n%>**){  %>


app.get("/contest/:name",(req,res)=>{
    var n=req.body.name
    res.render("file_name",{n:n,arr:arr});
    })
```

How do i access value of n and use it in if else condition in ejs file?